# How to override the onclick for SearchForm to specific action Sugarcrm

Tags: php, yui, sugarcrm, suitecrm

i have created a controller with action subscribers

like this

```
class LeadsController extends SugarController
{
public function action_subscriber()
{   
    $this->view = 'sub';     
}  
}
```

and i have added a button callled as subscribers in my search form

now on click on that button if i want to make search happen so i am calling SUGAR.savedViews.setChooser(); SUGAR.ajaxUI.submitForm(this.form); this two function in SearchFormGeneric.tpl

```
<input tabindex='2' title='go_select' id='go_select_b' ondblclick="SUGAR.savedViews.setChooser(); SUGAR.ajaxUI.submitForm(this.form);" class='button' type='button' name='subscriber' value='Subscriber'/>
```

but when i click on the button its going to

module=Leads&action=index

i have my logic written in action called subscriber , so when i click on my custom button it should search with .

module=Leads&action=subscriber

so how can i change the action on click of "SUGAR.savedViews.setChooser(); SUGAR.ajaxUI.submitForm(this.form); this function

[Search with this SUGAR.ajaxUI.submitForm(document.forms[‘DetailView’]); on post](http://developer.sugarcrm.com/2011/09/30/improving-sugarcrm-client-side-performance-the-sugarcrm-ajaxui/)

i found one post related to this and i tried some thing like this SUGAR.ajaxUI.submitForm(document.forms[‘SubView’]);, but it did not work.

[other post related to this](http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f6/how-override-onclick-searchform-75890/)

please can any one guide me on this ????

Comment: Hi All can some one guide me on this , i tried according my understanding and asked on crm forums but did not get any response  . it will be really appreciable if some can guide me on this ?

Comment: I don´t know anything about sugarcrm, im just a php developer, anyway here I go. What about overwrite your index action in LeadsController and do whatever you want there? Maybe redirect to your subscriber action... Because i understand that you can´t change the action value in your form, right?

Comment: index action is written in main class which is common for all modules , so i tried overwriting it but it was throwing error in application , so i created a separate action in controller which will redirect to separate view and extending the same index action ( listViewProcess() ) with custom search condition .

Comment: so  on search form SUGAR.ajaxUI.submitForm(this.form);  will redirect to direct index , but insted of that i want to to be search on specific action ? , so right now i am doing it with javascript on click function but i thnk that is not the standard way .

Comment: so, you have a form that do some search. Then you add a new button and when you click it the form has to go to your new action, but when you click the original submit button of the form it has to go to default action, is that right? One form, two possible actions?

Comment: yes , exactly . on search from the method SUGAR.ajaxUI.submitForm(this.form) is for default index action ,but  i want  to know how it can be trigger it on custom action . sorry English is not my native language so i beg your pardon for my grammar .

Comment: ok, i think you can do the following trick (sure is not the best way but i think it´ll work). You can put a hidden field in your form with default value 0, for example. Then add only a js function on the onClick event in your custom button that change the value of this field to 1, for example. Finally,according to the field value in the index action you´ll do the default search action if value is 0 or you´ll do your custom logic action if field value is 1. Assuming that you can modify index action.

Comment: @Tommy txs for your quick reply . as i have Manson above ,  i am already doing it with javascript on click function but i think that is not the standard way .

Comment: i thought you can´t solve the problem, sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally got the solution , so what we where trying was based on custom button on search view we were trying to modify the search .

so , go to search view under : 
suitecrm/custom/include/SearchForm/tpls/SearchFormGeneric.tpl

and add the button

```
{if $module eq 'o_order'}
    <input tabindex='2' title='Subscribers' id='get_report' onclick ="SUGAR.ajaxUI.submitForm(this.form);" class='button' type='submit' name='button' value='Subscribers'/>
{/if}
```

and put the condition under the method where we are generating the list based in search condition

go to  :  suitecrm/custom/modules/o_order/views/view.list.php

the function which is generating the list data based on query is listViewProcess()

```
    public function listViewProcess()        // genrating listview 
{
    $this->processSearchForm();
    $this->lv->searchColumns = $this->searchForm->searchColumns;
    if(!$this->headers)
        return;
    if(empty($_REQUEST['search_form_only']) || $_REQUEST['search_form_only'] == false){
        $this->lv->ss->assign("SEARCH",true);
        $this->lv->setup($this->seed, 'include/ListView/ListViewGeneric.tpl', $this->where, $this->params);
        $savedSearchName = empty($_REQUEST['saved_search_select_name']) ? '' : (' - ' . $_REQUEST['saved_search_select_name']);
        $configObject = new Configurator();
        $configObject->loadConfig();
        $configObject->config['save_query'] = 'no';
        $configObject->saveConfig();
        echo $this->lv->display();
        if($_REQUEST['button']=='Subscriber'){
            $this->getpdf($this->where);
        }
    }
}
```

so we are passing the search condition to getpdf() function as parameter

that's it do repair and rebuild from the admin log in and you can see the changes .

hope this helps some one !